# Weird ssh behavior - ssh sets PROMPT_COMMAND in unknown place

Tags: linux, bash, security, ssh

I've noticed recently weird behaviour of bash. It was reporting non-existing `preexec_set_exit` command or function. Small investigation showed that when I'm being logged through ssh `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable is set to following value:

```
   PROMPT_COMMAND=preexec_set_exit;preexec_invoke_cmd
```

It happens only on ssh, even when I'm logging into localhost.

Tried to grep through all files in `~/` and in `/etc` but no luck

I was installing and testing a while ago some tools and hacks from the net but can't remember what could cause the issue. Any ideas where this comes from or how to debug (and remove) it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Never mind. I've got it.

If anyone wants to know what happens when you're sshing into your box, and what helped me - it was:

```
    ssh host -t "bash --verbose --login"
```

Which in my case showed this:

```
    . /usr/share/undistract-me/long-running.bash
```

Which declares several hooks for handling long running commands using tricks like this one.

And that solves my worries about being hacked.